# Asset Pipeline doesn't find precompiled assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails 3.2 and I'm running on some issues running my production environment. I ran rake assets:precompile and then rails s -e production. Here is the error I got:

```
    Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError in Home#index 
    application_bottom.js isn't precompiled
```

But when I check to see what's in my public/assets I get

```
   ls public/assets/application_bottom*
   public/assets/application_bottom.js
   public/assets/application_bottom.js.gz
```

I noticed that I should probably have a file with the hash appended to it but I don't. I'm guessing that may be related to the issue but I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is my assets configure for the environment;

```
    config.serve_static_assets = true
    config.assets.compress = true
    config.assets.compile = false
    config.assets.digest = true
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you add application_bottom to the list of files that should be precompiled, this exists in the production.rb file inside of config/environments.

```
YOUR_APPLICATOIN_NAME::Application.configure do
  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w( application_bottom.js )
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had just figured this out. In my head the precompile task would find the manifestos inside my app/assets/jabacsripts and do it for me but I guess it makes default only for application.js/css. Thanks a lot!